# VSTest: A testsettings file or a runsettings with a ForcedLegacyMode set to true is not supported with the MSTest V2 Adapter. No test is available

Tags: visual-studio, vstest, vstest.console.exe

How to use `.testsettings` file running unit tests via `vstest.console.exe`? I created empty visual studio solution, created empty unit test project, added `Local.testsettings` file as a solution item.

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {

    }
}
```

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TestSettings name="Local" id="1109524d-9809-4423-b7fa-fad429ebfd8d" xmlns="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010">
  <Description>These are default test settings for a local test run.</Description>
  <Deployment enabled="false" />
  <Execution hostProcessPlatform="MSIL">
    <TestTypeSpecific>
      <UnitTestRunConfig testTypeId="13cdc9d9-ddb5-4fa4-a97d-d965ccfc6d4b">
        <AssemblyResolution>
          <TestDirectory useLoadContext="true" />
        </AssemblyResolution>
      </UnitTestRunConfig>
    </TestTypeSpecific>
    <AgentRule name="LocalMachineDefaultRole">
    </AgentRule>
  </Execution>
  <Properties />
</TestSettings>
```

Everything is ok when I run my tests with following command:

```
>> "[path to vstest]/vstest.console.exe" [path to project]\UnitTestProject1.dll
```

The command below gives an error.

```
"[path to vstest]/vstest.console.exe" [path to project]\UnitTestProject1.dll /Settings:[path to settings file]\Local.testsettings
```

> Warning : A testsettings file or a runsettings with a ForcedLegacyMode
>   set to true is not supported with the MSTest V2 Adapter. No test is
>   available in [path]\UnitTestProject1.dll. Make sure that test
>   discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version
>   settings are appropriate and try again.
>
> Additionally, path to test adapters can be specified using
>   /TestAdapterPath command. Example 
>   /TestAdapterPath:.

So I added `/TestAdapterPath:[project path/bin/Debug]` parameter. The `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.dll` with discoverer and executor is situated here. But I got the same error without the last sentence about specifying test adapter.

I was wondering if someone could solve this problem.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The solution is to use `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework` instead of `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework` which is added to your unit test project by Visual Studio by default. So you can remove two packages via `NuGet`. You should delete `MSTest.TestAdapter` and `MSTest.TestFramework` and install `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.Updated`. Your unit tests will be discovered after these steps.

Also you can read the following useful article about test framework [MSTest V2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/06/17/taking-the-mstest-framework-forward-with-mstest-v2/).

Comment: Your advice doesn't appear to be in the article you cite from Microsoft.  Where are you getting that information?

Comment: @DanEsparza This is article just a useful information and it doesn't contains the solution.

Comment: thanks! that put an end to the most boring rabbit hole ever :)

Answer (score 42):

I had the similar problem and I have resolved it the following way:

1. Go to *Test* ->
   *Test Settings*
2. Uncheck the `\..\..projectTestSettings.testsettings` file
3. Run the tests again

Comment: I did the same. But after that my unit test crashes before it enters the test case.

Comment: @apb_developer, probably the method provided in the answer is helpful, but it was something else that caused the tast to crash, for example, the contents of provided file. In my case, I provided `.runsettings` file and therefore was able to set ForceLegacyMode (inside MSTest section) to false. Surely, i had to check the new file instead of the previous default one.

Comment: this is the solution