# A testsettings file or a vsmdi file is not supported with the MSTest V2 Adapter

Tags: .net, unit-testing, azure-devops

On local I am getting "A testsettings file or a vsmdi file is not supported with the MSTest V2 Adapter", after following [VSTest: A testsettings file or a runsettings with a ForcedLegacyMode set to true is not supported with the MSTest V2 Adapter. No test is available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49758191/vstest-a-testsettings-file-or-a-runsettings-with-a-forcedlegacymode-set-to-true) link I am able to fix issue on local, however, still facing issue in Azure Devops pipeline where check build quality step fails with timeout error "Unable to get code coverage data within the maximum wait time."

Comment: Hi Pritam, Did you get a chance to implement the solution that I suggested? Were you able to resolve? If my reply helped or gave a right direction. Appreciate for  *marking it as an answer*  which will also help others in the community.

Answer (score 0):

The Build Quality Checks task currently supports two policies Warnings Policy & Code Coverage Policy. According to your description and error info, seems there were something wrong with your Code Coverage Policy.

When you want to use the Code Coverage Policy you need to **make sure that you publish code coverage values calculated by your test tool first.**

The Policy itself does not calculate the code coverage. Before you add the task and activate the policy, **please make sure that you can already see code coverage values in your build summary.**